# ASP .NET CORE 2.2 Razor pages with python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building a website through Visual Studio with razor pages.

I have a python script written in python 3.7, which I want to call from the website. I know that I can call a python script from C#, but is it possible to embed a python installation in a razor pages project, such that I can call my python script within my application straight from the website?

I have tried looking around, and haven't found a solution yet, the only solutions are with IronPython, which will not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding about how a solution like this works. What you're asking for is really not standard practice, or either not recommended or possible. Using a library like IronPython will only get you so far.

You need to do research into something like HTTP REST APIs. Your C# application could then send an HTTP request to your Python application and get a result back.

The flow might look like this:

User Makes HTTP Request to your .NET app -> .NET makes HTTP request to Python app using WebClient -> Python runs task and returns result to .NET -> .NET returns result to user.

Other ways to do it are using messaging protocols such as RPC, or a message broker similar to RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka. These latter options are better for applications with a lot of requests going back and forth.

**See these links:**

Building a REST API in Python: https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

Building a REST API in .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2